Psych library: factor analysis not convergence with mixed data
I want to compute factor analysis with mixed data (i.e., continous, categorical and binary) but I have a lot of warnings and it does not converge resulting in Nans ( objective num NaN,
criteria NaN NA NA, STATISTIC    : num NaN, PVAL         : num NaN)
with pchisq not converged in 1000000 iter and GPFoblq convergence not obtained in GPFoblq. 1000 iterations used)
mixedCor_results <-mixedCor(data,p=4:93,c=1:2,d=3,correct=FALSE,smooth=TRUE,global= FALSE)
ggcorrplot(mixedCor_results$rho)

#Compute the factors
parallel <- fa.parallel(mixedCor_results$rho,n.obs=nrow(data), fa="fa", main = "Scree   
Plot",correct=FALSE ,n.iter = 50)
print(parallel$nfact) #number of factors
modelfa= fa(mixedCor$rho,n.obs=nrow(data), nfactors = 38,correct=FALSE ,n.iter = 50)

str(modelfa)
print(modelfa$loadings, cut = 0)

I wonder if there is a bug in mixedcor. I tried with mixedcor and it is not working but with fa parallel and polychor works if I remove continous and i leave only categorical and binary but if i add mixed with continous in fa parallel is not working again as it is using mixedcor internally and giving warnings again
#REMOVE CONTINOUS THEN IT WORKS
data <- data[ -c(1:4)]
#POLY used for binary and categorical
parallel <- fa.parallel(data,fa="fa",cor="poly",correct=0,n.iter = 50)    
#Compute the factors
modelfa= fa(data, fm = "ml",cor="poly",nfactors = 23,fa="fa",
rotate = "varimax", 
scores="Bartlett",correct=0)

Someone had the same issue?. Is it ok to use the polychoric including the binary and internally the lib uses the correct correlation (tetrachoric)? If this is the case I will transform the continous. But the mixedCor is not working propertly.
